# Recursive templates - constant n size array -> n-1 size in-place?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

This may be a bizarre question, but I have a recursive template that expects an array of size d (where d is a template parameter), and I want to pass the d-1 template the same array as if it was one element shorter. This way I only work with one array, instead of creating a new one for each level.

I feel like the answer may be something very basic, but I can't come up with any search terms that result in anything close to what I'm looking for.

To put this into context, here's an example

```
template<int d>
void Function(int array[d])
{
  array[d- 1]= d;
  Function<d- 1>(?);
}
```

Comment: what exactly is the question? Could you provide that recursive template source?

Comment: Should've put in an example! I just added one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is for static, C-style arrays, If your question is about std::Array, I apologize.

Off the top of my head, I came up with two ways to do the recursion, but many more techniques exist.

The first one uses a partially specialized class (with array count of zero) to terminate the recursion.

The second way uses a cast to a statically-chosen type which ends the recursion with an overloaded function.  Here, I cast the array to void*, but for types that won't work with this, you could create a custom type which is constructible from the original type.

I resorted to using reinterpret_cast to change the array's type from a reference to array[count] to array[count-1].  Although I expect this to be safe as it is used here, keep in mind that you might run into problems in different situations.

```
#include <iostream>

// Ends recursion with a partial specialization
template <typename T, int count>
struct StaticArrayDump {
    static void func(T(&a)[count]) {
        using shorter_t = T(&)[count-1];
        StaticArrayDump<T, count-1>::func(reinterpret_cast<shorter_t>(a));
        std::cout << a[count-1] << ' ';
    }
};
template <typename T>
struct StaticArrayDump<T,0> { 
    static void func(...) {}
};

template <typename T, int count>
static void static_array_dump_spec(T(&a)[count]) {
    using shorter_t = T(&)[count-1];
    StaticArrayDump<T,count>::func(a);
}

// Ends recursion with void* cast and function overload
// Ultimately relies on type_select's specialization, however
template <bool, typename A, typename B> struct type_select /* true */ { using type = A; };
template <typename A, typename B>       struct type_select<false,A,B> { using type = B; };
template <bool cond, typename A, typename B>
using type_select_t = typename type_select<cond, A, B>::type;

static void static_array_dump_ovld(...) {}

template <typename T, int count>
static void static_array_dump_ovld(T(&a)[count]) {
    static const int next_count = count-1;
    using shorter_t = T(&)[next_count];
    static_array_dump_ovld(reinterpret_cast<
            type_select_t<next_count!=0, shorter_t, void*>
        >(a));
    // output the last element
    std::cout << a[count-1] << ' ';
}

// This is an overload-based version which is free of
// any reliance on template specialization.
// helper_trueol's (void*, void*) overload will only be
// selected for arguments (array_ref, count) when count
// is 0, because 0 is the only integer which can be
// converted to a pointer.

// This one's compiler compatibility is a bit shaky...
// MSVC 2013 OK
// IdeOne g++ needs int cast for next_count
static void helper_trueol(void*, void*) {}

template <typename T, int count>
static void helper_trueol(T(&a)[count], int) {
    static const int next_count = count-1;
    using shorter_t = T(&)[next_count];
    helper_trueol(reinterpret_cast<shorter_t>(a), int(next_count));
    std::cout << a[count-1] << ' ';
}

template <typename T, int count>
static void static_array_dump_trueol(T(&a)[count]) {
    helper_trueol(a, count);
}

// Finally, this overload-based version relies
// on SFINAE to disqualify the template function
// as a candidate when count is 0 because the
// zero-length array type triggeres a substitution
// failure.
// So just using this template array argument type,
// the same one used in all of the previous examples,
// but without any extra mechanisms, is all you need
// to end this recursion!  
// This is the obvious best way, of course.

static void static_array_dump_sfinae(...) {}

template <typename T, int count>
static void static_array_dump_sfinae(T(&a)[count]) {
    static const int next_count = count-1;
    using shorter_t = T(&)[next_count];
    static_array_dump_sfinae(reinterpret_cast<shorter_t>(a));
    std::cout << a[count-1] << ' ';
}

//////

int main() {
    double dbl_array[] = { 0, 1.2, 3.4, 5.6789, 10 };
    static_array_dump_spec(dbl_array);
    std::cout << '\n';
    const char* cstr_array[] = { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four" };
    static_array_dump_ovld(cstr_array);
    std::cout << '\n';

    char charray[] = "Hello";
    charray[sizeof(charray)-1] = '!'; // replace nul terminator
    static_array_dump_trueol(charray);
    std::cout << '\n';

    bool barray[] = {true, true, true, false, true, false, false, false};
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    static_array_dump_sfinae(barray);
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer! I can't believe I didn't think of reinterpret cast- I guess was unsure how things worked with constant sized arrays I didn't think to just force the cast. The rest of your answer was very helpful as well because (as you show) there's some other thorns in implementing this particular recursion. I had already figured out the partial specialization with structs, but I didn't know about the second method you posted.

Comment: Thanks!  The "overload" version leverages class specialization in type_select, so it is technically also specialization-based, but I think a true overload-based technique should still be possible. The reinterpret_cast worries me, but strict aliasing should not be violated as long as the array is accessed by accessing each element, rather than somehow as a whole unit, like might be done by embedding it in a struct.

Comment: I added two more techniques.  The last one is by far the best, and really the only way to end the recursion.  Lol

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I am interpreting this correctly but, when you pass the array as a template, I assume you pass an argument for the size of the array. (otherwise how would you know how large the array is?) When you pass the array, you are passing a pointer to the first element of the array, so when you pass the sub array you could just pass a pointer to the next element and size d-1 or an iterator that points to the next element and size d-1.

Example:

```
template< typename T>
T foo(T * ptr, int size) {
    if (size > 0)
        return *ptr + foo(ptr + sizeof(T), size - 1);
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: The arrays are constant sized; the size is a template parameter.

Comment: If that is the case I don't think what you want is possible, template arguments have to be static because the function is constructed with the template type at compile time and not run time.

Comment: The parameter is still constant if its the result of a constant and another constant though. Such as d- 1 (where d was a template parameter).

Comment: Why do you want to do this with a template parameter? Wouldn't it be easier to just pass d as a function parameter and not as a template parameter?

Comment: I am trying to see whether I can improve performance by taking advantage of the fact that my arrays are very small (<10 elements) and constant sized. Also, I was just curious about how it could be done.

Answer (score 0):

From the information that you provided i assume you want too know how too "stop" the recursion. This would look something like this:

```
// this is the function that will be called from the user, it would be bad design too have to pass an integral constant manually when we can easily do this 
template <std::size_t I>
inline 
void Function(int (&_array)[I])
{
  Function(_array, std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>);
}

// function will recursively do something with an array for each of it's elements
template<std::size_t I>
void Function(int (&_array)[I], std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>)
{
  // do something...
  Function(_array,std::integral_constant<std::size_t,I-1>);
}

// function as before with a few modifications
template<std::size_t I>
void Function(int (&_array)[I], std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 1>)
{
  // do something...
  // exit function...
}
```

Comment: I actually was just curious about how to take the input of T[d] and make it a t[d-1] without creating a new array.